# Unable to retrieve success response via requests from API

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am attempting to use a facial recognition API and am still new to the requests package. The code I have written is posted below.

```
import requests

baseURL = "https://api-live.wiseai.tech"
appKey = "--------"
appSecret = "----------"

def createFaceDB(appKey, appSecret, libraryName, thresholds):

    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    body = {
      "appKey": appKey,
      "appSecret": appSecret,
      "libraryName": libraryName,
      "thresholds": thresholds
    }

    r = requests.post("http://api-live.wiseai.tech", data= body, headers=headers)
    return r.text

print(createFaceDB(appKey, appSecret, "test", 1))
```

The documentation for the API states that there is either going to be a successful requests or an unsuccessful one. If either occurs I am suppose to get either success message or an error message respectively. The error messages vary such as **ERROR_KEY_ISNOT_LEGAL** indicating there is something incorrect with the API key or **BAD_REQUEST** indicating there are missing parameters.

Unfortunately, when I run the code I get back a bunch of gibberish on the command prompt. Not receiving a successful or unsuccessful request. Furthermore, if I incorrectly put in the API key expecting to receive a error message I get the same output in the console.

Both API and appSecret keys are correct and available. Unfortunately, at this moment I am unable to share them.

I've added more information the question along with images. Linked below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QWuW.jpg

Edit 1: Some of the other things I've tried is setting **json=body**. Another thing is that the output display grecaptcha at the end of it (as displayed in the image). Just wanted to point that out, not sure exactly what its suppose to mean.

Edit 2: It seems that even though the body consists of 4 values and the definition expects 4 parameters if I remove appKey and appSecret I get the same results on the console. Perhaps there is another command I could use instead of **requests.post()**

Comment: The `baseURL` variable starts with `https:`, but you're using `http:` for the actual request.  Which is it supposed to be?

Comment: Also, you're setting a JSON content-type header, but you're not actually sending json.  Use `json=body` instead of `data=body` to send the data in json format.

Comment: I've tried setting the body to both **body=body** and **json=body**. As for the http, I received an email from the API providers stating that the url starts will **https**. I have also just tried it using just **http** but it gave the same results.

Comment: A questions out of curiosity, the base URL is the endpoint correct ? The email I have received from them also says that **The API end point is https://api-live.wiseai.tech**

Comment: If the developers say you should use https, then use that.  Don't bother with http.

Comment: Have you carefully examined the "gibberish" you get back from the request, to see if it contains a useful error message?

Comment: The grecaptcha (posted as image) seems to indicate the request is getting shunted to a CAPTCHA page, it may be that I am not logged in correctly and/or I'm not actually accessing the API site correctly. This is suggested by a user on reddit. (also posted the question there). Other then that I can't really tell there is simply too much appearing on the console and most of it is unreadable, apart from some code which seems irrelevant to the issue at hand.